# Python packages for numerical data imputation

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, python, data-imputation

I am working with multivariate numerical data with a lot of missing values (so dropping all entries or columns with missing data is not an option).

Is there a Python package for data imputation?

I am interested mainly in methods based on linear regression (plus estimation of variance of the predicted variable).

Comment: Why votes to close? I don't see in FAQ anything against this kind of questions...

Comment: This question is about how to work w/ Python, not about the statistical ideas associated w/ imputation. Thus it is off-topic for CV, but should be on-topic on SO. Moreover, there is a large & active group of users on SO who work w/ Python, so you should be able to get good answers there. It's certainly not personal.

Comment: @gung If "How to use linear regression for missing data imputation in Python" is not about statistical ideas in Python then what is? (Unless all software questions are off-topic; but there is no shortage of questions of type "How to do [a statistical procedure] in R?"...) I am afraid that asking about statistical tools on SO is not the best, or the most on-topic, idea (especially as I need to go beyond imputing mean or median).

Comment: *How to use linear regression for missing data?* is clearly on-topic for CV. Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify that this is your real question. The only question I see, as currently written, is "Is there a Python package for data imputation?", which is an SO question, not a CV question.

Comment: At this moment there are 213,086 tags for Python on SO and 184 here. That said, I don't know how well "is there a package" questions go down with the Python community there. Aren't there ways of searching? (If you did search before posting this question, spelling out that you did and that you found nothing makes it clear that it's hard to find anything.)

Answer (score 3):

scikit-learn has an "Imputer" class you should look into.

- [API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)
- [Overview](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)
- [Demo](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/imputation.html)

EDIT: Looks like this class doesn't support imputing from a linear model. You could always try modifying the sklearn code to support it, maybe even submit a pull request: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py

EDIT2: Looks like you might have better luck with the more versatile imputation faculties available in the [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.feature.imputation.html) library.

Comment: Putting mean or median is not enough for my purpose - I want to calculate distance between points and putting mean makes points with missing values too close to each other (it was my initial approach, in `pandas`). As of now I made a script for myself.

Comment: Did you check out the `Orange` library, or just `sklearn`?

Comment: Now I am testing `Orange` and according to its documentation it should work. However, I am struggling with importing data to it (it's anything but trivial - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986719/how-do-i-create-a-new-data-table-in-orange but I am still figuring out how to convert `numpy.NaN`s to missing oranges).

Comment: There is now
`from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer` This allows linear regression, bayesian ridge regression and many other regressors.